# Modulus operator returning quotient instead of remainder

Tags: c, math

I am currenly  attempting to implement a basic pairing function in c. The pairing function will take in 2 unsigned integers and output a single unsigned long value. In order to unpair the result and retrieve the original values, the modulus operator must be used. But for some reason the modulues operator is returning the quotient and not the remainder like it is supposed to.

Here is the code:

```
unsigned long pair(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
    return (unsigned long)UINT_MAX * y + x;
}

unsigned int depair_x(unsigned long z)
{
    return (unsigned int)(z % UINT_MAX);
}

unsigned int depair_y(unsigned long z)
{
    return (unsigned int)(z / UINT_MAX);
}
```

A good example is that when I input the values `1058242433` and `1063370847` I get the result `4567143011379691298`. However the result of the modulus operator is roughly `1063370847`, which is incorrect (feel free to check it). However that result is the quotient. What is happening here?

Comment: Please show the code that calls these functions in addition to input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: The value you show as the result of the modulus is *the same as* the value you say you give for the `x` part - which is what it should be, from what I can make out from your question. Can you add some details, please?

Comment: I tried your code with the two inputs you give and I do, indeed, get the same paired value; but I also get those very same two originals from the respective depair functions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like "off-by-1".

In order to achieve "to unpair the result and retrieve the original values" a scale of `UINT_MAX + 1UL` is needed, not `UINT_MAX`.

```
// return (unsigned long)UINT_MAX * y + x;
return (UINT_MAX + 1UL)* y + x;

//return (unsigned int)(z % UINT_MAX);
return (unsigned int)(z % (UINT_MAX + 1ul)); 

// Likewise for `/`
```

---

If `unsigned long` has same range as `unsigned`, look to using `unsigned long long` instead of `unsigned long`.